# Is there any way to tell angular-cli (for angular 2) to generate minified version of css?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

As the title says, when I run "ng serve" angular-cli generates normal css whereas I expect to get the minified version.
Is there any specific setting to use for angular-cli-build, or some additional plugin to install and use?

This is my angular-cli-build.js

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');


module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'angular2-cookie/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to get a minified version when developing? (`ng serve` is meant to be a development tool as you develop your applciation) To get a minified version of the application, run `ng build --prod`

Comment: thanks mate, I did'n know it, I mean I thought it was better dev with min ones, but obviously it takes more time

Comment: I want it during development exactly so I can keep track of how big my app is. I want to run `ng new`, then `ng serve --prod` and then view the sizes of the files. I might only do it once, but it's easier than doing a dist build which I'm not actually even sure if there's a way to ng serve a 'dist' folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
# --env=<your_env>
# --no-sourcemap
# minify => ./minify.js
ng build --env=prod --no-sourcemap && node minify
```

minify.js

```
// npm i --save-dev minifier fs-jetpack

const jetpack = require('fs-jetpack');
const path = require('path');
const minifier = require('minifier');

const files = jetpack.list(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'));

console.log(files);

for (const file of files) {
  if (/.*(\.js|\.css)$/g.test(file)) {
    console.log(`Start ${file}`);
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', file);
    minifier.minify(filePath, {output: filePath});
  }
}

console.log('End');
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version

Answer (score 41):

```
ng build --prod --env=prod
```

or

```
ng serve --prod
```

Will minify and add a file hash for you.

- the `--prod` tells it to minify hash, and gzip.
- the `--env=prod` tells it to use your prod environment constants file.

[which would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrJXh.png)

Comment: This is a bit confusing, why would you need to specify both `--prod` and `--env=prod`? I notice that I get different output if  I leave out `--prod`. Is there anyway to update the prod env file to actually be prod and include the `--prod` command?

Comment: The latest [Angular documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/application-environments.md) states that in order to change environment files, use `--configuration=prod`

Answer (score 3):

James' commands DO work and DO minify even when using `ng serve --prod`.

However you may see something like the following in Chrome and get confused:

[image]

That doesn't look minified does it!

Look more carefully and you'll see `js:formatted` indicating that the pretty print feature was enabled.

Opening the URL `http://localhost:4200/main.5082a3da36a8d45dfa42.js` directly in a new tab showed me that the CLI was indeed minifying it fully.

You can click the `{}` icon to turn this feature off, but it seems to like to disappear once the code has been pretty printed so you may need to reload the page and click it quickly.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 it is just enough to use `--prod` flag, when building project:

```
ng build --prod
```